# MYSQL Select employee couples who where in the same hotel at the same time

Tags: mysql, sql

Hey im struggling with a mysql query.

I have to select `PNr, HName, arrivalDate` from pairs of employees which are in the same hotel with equal arrival date. These pairs should be sorted ASCENDING.

Any ideas? Im new to complex mysql queries and can't figure it out.

Table employees

```
| #PNr |   Name   |  ANr  | Gehalt |

|  1  |   Herald |   4   |    28000      | 
|  2  |   Gudru  |   4   |    28000      | 
|  3  |   Tim    |   1   |    32000      |
|  4  |   Fred   |   1   |    32000      |
|  5  |   Frieda |   2   |    27500      |
```

Table hotel

```
| #HNr |   HName |  Kategorie| PLZ         | Ort

|  1  |   A   |      4      |    1234     | Memphis
|  2  |   B   |      4      |    1234     | New York 
|  3  |   C   |      1      |    1234     | Berlin
|  4  |   D   |      1      |    1234     | LA
```

Table travel

```
| #*employee| #*Hotel  |  #arrivalDate        | Duration  | Costs

|  1        |      1   |      12.11.2020      |    7     | 1200
|  1        |      4   |      31.10.2019      |    14    | 2800 
|  3        |      4   |      31.10.2019      |    14    | 2800
|  5        |      3   |      09.09.2019      |    3     | 1750
```

`# is primary Key, * is foreign key`

Comment: Have you tried writing a query yet yourself?

Comment: yes I have tried that a lot  for hours!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `exists` for filtering:

```
select 
    e.pnr, 
    h.name, 
    t.arrivalDate
from employees e
inner join travel t 
    on t.employee = e.pnr
    and exists (
        select 1
        from travel t1
        where 
            t1.hotel = t.hotel
            and t1.arrivalDate = t.arrivalDate
            and t1.employee <> t.employee
    )
inner join hotel h 
    on h.hnr = t.hotel
```

Or, in MySQL 8.0, you can do a window count in a subquery and then filter in the outer query:

```
select prn, name, arrivalDate
from (
    select 
        e.pnr, 
        h.name, 
        t.arrivalDate,
        count(*) over(partition by h.hnr, t.arrivalDate) cnt
    from employees e
    inner join travel t on t.employee = e.pnr
    inner join hotel h on h.hnr = t.hotel
) 
where cnt > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple one.

```
    select  e.pnr, h.name, t.arrivalDate
    from employees e
        inner join travel t on t.employee = e.pnr
        inner join hotel h on h.hnr = t.hotel
    where h.arrivalDate in (
                select t.arrivalDate
                from employees e
                    inner join travel t on t.employee = e.pnr
                    inner join hotel h on h.hnr = t.hotel
                group by t.arrivalDate
                having count(*) > 1
    )
```